# Can I safely wrap the current request in a static instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, multi-tenant, separation-of-concerns

I'm working on a multi-tenant web application. At the beginning of each request, the web application will use either the URL or a cookie to determine the tenant ID of the current request. I want to make this available to my data layer so that it can automatically include the ID in SQL queries without having to explicitly pass it down through the layers for each query. However, I don't want my data layer to be dependent on System.Web or to only be usable by a web application.

So I've created an interface in the data layer `ITenantIDProvider`

```
public interface ITenantIDProvider
{
    Guid GetTenantID();
}
```

And it could be implemented something like this:

```
public class TenantIDProvider : ITenantIDProvider
{
    public Guid GetFacilityID()
    {
        return (Guid)HttpContext.Current.Items["TenantID"];
    }
}
```

In reality it will be something more complex than just retrieving from `Items`  but the key is that it will be using the current request. There is also a business logic layer in between but it just forwards the ID along so I left that code out for simplicity.

When the web application starts it passes a new instance of `TenantIDProvider` to the data layer which passes it into an instance of a custom EntityFramework `IDbContextInterceptor`:

```
//Static method in data layer called at application start up
public static void SetTenantIDProvider(ITenantIDProvider tenantIDProvider)
{
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(new MyContextInterceptor(tenantIDProvider));
}
```

`DbInterception.Add` only gets called once at application startup so I believe it's storing the given interceptor in a static collection, which means my interceptor instance is common to all requests. However, since my tenantIDProvider is just wrapping access to the current request (and importantly, not setting any instance variables) I shouldn't need to worry about a race condition right? I've attempted to debug through two threads, freezing them at different times to test it and it seems to work as intended. I just feel a little uneasy about an instance of an object that is shared by all threads/requests trying to access request-specific data.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Web Form or MVC?

Comment: My web app is MVC. It could potentially be either or neither as far as the BL and data layers needs to be concerned.

Comment: Couple of points here, 1st is to get rid of the HttpContext and use other means as if you later move this to a windows service / worker role / webjob, the HttpContext would not exist. 2nd, you can prefer to use the lock in the method so that in-case of a race condition, there would be strictly access to 1 thread only. Also if you have a common logic for the tenant's, it is advisable to use an Asynchronous method

Comment: On your first point, the web application is the one referencing `HttpContext`. The `TenantIDProvider` class, which is in the web application, encapsulates  the access to the `HttpContext`. An instance of `TenantIDProvider` is passed to the logic layer which wraps it and passes it to the data layer. The data layer doesn't know or care that the ID is coming from `HttpContext`. Another application could implement an `ITenantIDProvider` however it wants.